# determine file extension in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Right now I'm getting file as a string and I need to iterate through every known ex. case to grab it's file extension.

How can I determine file extension in runtime using c# without iterating for expected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Path.GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method provided by the framework.

> The extension of the specified path **(including the period ".")**, or
>   null, or String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns null. If
>   path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns
>   String.Empty.

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(@"C:\mydir\file.exe");
```

You will get `.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using something like

[Path.GetExtension()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)

> The extension of the specified path (including the period "."), or
>   null, or String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns null. If
>   path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns
>   String.Empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Path.GetExtension()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

> The extension of the specified path (**including the period "."**), or
>   `null`, or `String.Empty`. If path is `null`, `GetExtension` returns `null`. If
>   path does not have extension information, `GetExtension` returns
>   `String.Empty`.

```
string p = @"C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Test.txt";

string e = Path.GetExtension(p);
if (e == ".txt")
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

`Path.GetExtension` checks the entire path for invalid chars. This step is redundant if you already know your path is valid, such as when you received it from `Directory.GetFile`s. It looks for a separator char. The implementation checks for `DirectorySeparatorChar`, `AltDirectorySeparatorChar`, and `VolumeSeparatorChar`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Path.GetExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx):

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(@"C:\myfile.txt");
```

Or, did you mean you want to search for a file with a given base name and any extension? You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "myfile.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way in finding it..

```
var file = new FileInfo("myPath");
var extension = file.Extension;
```

So for example if we wanna take all txt files from a directory we can do like this :

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("myFolder");
var filesWithTxtExtension = directory.GetFiles().Where(file => file.Extension == ".txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [System.IO.FileInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx).
It has a property called [Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension.aspx) which gives you a string containing the extension part of the file name.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("myfile.txt")
string fileExtension = file.Extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Path.GetExtension(path)` it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
string getFileExtension (string Path)
{
return Path.GetExtension(Path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
```

From [MSDN - Path.GetExtension Method](http://www.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx)